# Make slow when selecting the accordion menu hover effect

Tags: jquery

My question is how could do more slowly hover effect when you go from one tab to another tab?

```
if ($('#section ul').length) {
    $("#section ul").accordion({
        event: "mouseover",
        active: 1,
        collapsible: false,
        autoHeight: false,
        animated: 'swing',
        duration: 1000
    }).mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).accordion('activate', "#mainmenu");
    });
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jphuP/

Answer (score 0):

Change `duration` to `animate`: [API](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/)

Comment: The problem itself is not the time of the effect, but when you mouse the effect to the other tab is too fast.